# Recreating the signature sound from "Epic"

Tags: sound-design, beginner

I'm curious to know if anyone has ever made this sound themselves or have an idea on how to recreate this sound. I use Propellerheads Reason 7 and would love to recreate this sound to use in some of my songs.

Here's the link

The sound starts at around 0:45 in.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like a stuccato pan flute to me. Maybe a synthetic version.

Here's a link:
[Stuccato Pan Flute](http://youtu.be/aCR1j85BcaQ)

Could also be another wooden instrument though.

Comment: I definitely agree on the pan flute, or at least a synthesized approximation of one. The attack sounds a bit artificial though, so you might not necessarily need to start with a _staccato_ sample.

Answer (score 2):

It is definitely a sampled plucky sound. I can clearly hear it get longer on the lower notes.

To get the sound, set up a track with a simple FM Pluck synth, then give it thick distortion, delays, and reverb to make the sound deliciously big.